# Winsock only accepts connection from the same computer, but not from the same network

Tags: c, tcp, winsock, winsock2

So I have been following this guide
http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/
To create a simple tcp server in c, this is the code I came up with :
https://pastebin.com/CDxiLv3b

```
int c;
char client_message[2000];
int recv_size;
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

printf("Initialised.\n");

//Create a socket
if ((server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
}

printf("Server Socket created.\n");

memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

//Bind
if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
}

printf("Bind to port %d done.\n", port);

//Listen to incoming connections
listen(server_socket, 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming reverse shell...");

c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
while ((client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    puts("Connection accepted");
    if ((recv_size = recv(client_socket, client_message, 2000, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
        break;
    }
    client_message[recv_size] = '\0';
    strcpy_s(path, MAX_PATH_LEN, client_message);
    break;
}

if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

return 0;
```

(Yes I basicly copied and changed stuff)
Now the problem is that I can only connect to this server using the same connection I cant connect to it using diffrent computers in the network and even if I open port (which shouldn't actually matter) it wont accept the connection from the diffrent computers on my network (only from the same computer)

Comment: Define 'won't work'.

Comment: On what interface (ip) is the program listening (you can check with netstat) and which ip are you using to connect from the other machine?

Comment: won't work means it wont accept connections from other computers in the network I will test it now (the ip listining thing) and in both my local computer (where it work) and the other computer in my network I use my local ip (10.0.0.14)

Comment: No. 'Won't work' means the clients get an error. What is it?

Comment: @Juan , it shows on 10.0.0.14:25565 (I used mc port cus I have it already opened port)

Comment: @EJP I have updated the description of my problem

Comment: @Juan this is what it shows TCP    10.0.0.14:25565        Barr-PC:52130          TIME_WAIT

Comment: @Juan nvm while listing it wont even show on netstat

Comment: If you can ping the machine 10.0.0.14 (with the server program) from the other computer, it coul be the firewall not letting you access port 25565.

Comment: @Juan the thing is that I can see the other computer's TCP packets in wire shark and I already used 25565 when I used a java server I just can't use it using the C server

Comment: It still could be a firewall thing, because rules can be set by program. Perhaps the jvm has permission and you new program (the .exe you compile) doesn't.

Comment: @Juan Nvm that was it !

Comment: What part of 'the clients get an error: what is it?' didn't you understand?

Comment: Sorry, what is Nvm? I saw you also mentioned it before.

Comment: @juan it is a short for nevermind

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to open ports on the firewall